# Where is the nginx executable on Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, executable, nginx

I've installed the nginx-light package on debian, but I can't find the executable. It's not in `/usr/bin`, like it says on the official nginx website. Where is it, then?

Comment: execute in your terminal `whereis nginx`

Comment: @user3566929 doesn't show anything, just `nginx: `

Comment: maybe you typed it wrong as the output is supposed to be this `nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz
`

Comment: oh, I was ssh'd into a server with nginx installed, but I was running the command on my local machine accidentally. When I run it on the actual server I get the correct output.

Answer (score 4):

To get a list of all the files installed by a package, you can use

```
dpkg -L <package_name>
```

In your case

```
dpkg -L nginx-light
```

will list all the files installed by the package. Look at that list to know where the executable has been installed. Also, if you know the executable's name beforehand, you can filter the list of files with `grep`:

```
dpkg -L nginx-light | grep '.*/nginx$'
```

Replace `nginx` above by the actual name of the `nginx` executable.

Comment: This is probably the better answer, but the other one is more to the point

Comment: @Markasoftware agreed (on both counts :) ). I deliberately made my answer generic in the hope that it would work in more general situations.